# Empty value for ObjectID=1

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator

When I try to use field calculator in ArcGIS with polygon data in a geodatabase, I get an error "Empty value for ObjectID=1". I can manually change that field but when I try to use field calculator, I get an error. If I try to calculate the field with different sorting, I get the same error, e.g. "Empty value for ObjectID=252845".

What could be the problem?

Comment: You may have a corrupt layer, export it to a new layer and try the field calculation again.

Comment: I tried exporting, it's the same.

Comment: Try running Repair Geometry tool on it, http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/repair-geometry.htm